# If n is a positive integer , find the sum of $ S_n = 1+2+\cdots+n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

$$ S_n = 1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
How do I go about solving this ? I tried to search for a solution, but I didn't find anything ( well I didn't know what this was called to even look for it in the first place).

Comment: Gauss solved this!

Comment: Try searching "Induction".

Comment: okay thanks i'll try looking into those

Comment: Search tip: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+sum+of+integers+n

Comment: @HansLundmark yeah that one is it, i'll check it out now

Comment: Incase you are a visual or tactile learner:  you can draw a triangular "stair case" that has 1 step, then 2 steps, then 3 .... then $n$.  Then draw another of these.  Turn one upside down and put it on top of the other... and you have a rectangle made up  $n$ by $n+1$ steps.  https://latex.artofproblemsolving.com/4/2/3/4234a9f1ce8beb18aab9f27831bf936117909db1.png

Comment: @fleablood Oh! thanks that really makes it alot easier to understand

Comment: Another way to think of it (these are *all* the exact same proofs; just different ways of looking at them).  Consider what the average of 1, 2,3,4,5.....n is.  Is they are evenly distributed the average is right smack dab in the middle:  $\frac {n+1}2$.  And there are $n$ terms so they add up to $n*\frac {n+1}2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $$1+2+3+4+...+97+98+99+100=(1+100)+(2+99)+(3+98)+...$$
Can you solve this? the reult is $5050$ and now you can try it with variables!

Comment: oh okay. thanks, I think I understand how it works now

Comment: I think it's equal to $5050$ not $5040$, right?

Comment: @user464154 Yes, it should be 5050.

Answer (score 1):

Write $S:=1+2+\cdots+n$ and consider
$$
\begin{matrix}
S & = & 1 & + & 2 & + & \cdots & + & (n-1) & + & n \\
S & = & n & + & (n-1) & + & \cdots & + & 2 &  + & 1 \\
2S & = & (n+1) & + & (n+1) & + & \cdots & + & (n+1) & + & (n+1).
\end{matrix}
$$
Then $2S=n(n+1)$, which implies $S=n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: why did you write $(n-1)$ ? thats the part I'm having difficulty understanding edit: never mind i just realized it, man the sleepiness is getting to my head apparently

Comment: @user464154 I'm just writing the sum $1+2+\cdots+(n-1)+n$ backwards, which is $n+(n-1)+\cdots+2+1$.

Comment: okay thanks! i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

$$2S_n=(1+n)+(2+n-1)+...+(n+1)=n(n+1),$$
which gives $$S_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the square of side length  $s=n $.  Divide it diagonally in half.  That gives  $\frac {n^2}2$.  Now go along the diagonal and "fill in " the missing half of each  $1×1$ square, for $n\cdot \frac12$.  Add the two to get  $1+2+\dots+n $.